# What is the best way to implement dynamic borders in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, spacing, android-relativelayout

I have a list of items each of which is basically two checkboxes separated with a view divider.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- VIEW 1 -->
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="VIEW 1"
        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"/>

    <!-- SEPARATOR -->
    <View android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <!-- VIEW 2 -->
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="VIEW 2"
        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`drawable/checkbox_background.xml` is a selector with two solid shapes - white for an unchecked state and red for a checked one.

This is what the list view looks like:

[image: views_before]

What I'm trying to achieve is **get rid of the divider when either of its adjacent checkboxes is checked** (in fact, I have more than two):

[image: views_after]

As per my understanding, my options are:

1. Set the separator's visibility to `View.GONE` when a checkbox sets in a checked state. But it forces view1 and view2 to redraw and shift their texts a little closer to the center, which doesn't look nice.
2. Overlap view1 and view2 at the edges using negative margins by the width of the separator, and then put the separator over them. Then I could make it `View.INVISIBLE`. But this technique requires RelativeLayout, and I can't use RelativeLayout because I need to space my checkboxes evenly across the screen.
3. Add another (red) separator and show one at a time. But this is just ugly.
4. Change separator's `LayoutParams` (height) and background. Probably my best bet so far.

Are there any better solutions? Maybe some that don't require to do things programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may nest `LinearLayout` with check buttons in `RelativeLayout` and put your divider over them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- VIEW 1 -->
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:text="VIEW 1"/>

        <!-- VIEW 2 -->
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:text="VIEW 2"/>

    <!-- SEPARATOR -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you don't need to have exactly 8dp margins and can set fixed height for your divider you may use `FrameLayout`. It has better performance, because it's less complicated view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- checkboxes -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- SEPARATOR -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that both of these solutions only work for two views, when the only divider is placed at the center. But my layout has more than two checkboxes in a row, so I need the dividers to be placed relative to them.

Comment: Okay, what about `LinearLayout` with `CheckBox`es and `View`s where you change separator background color to red when previous and next checkbox are selected? Otherwise change bg color back to `@android:color/holo_green_light`.